# How to Style a Tool Tip in Html ActionLink

Tags: css, asp.net, tooltip

I have a HtmlAction Link with a tool tip displayed on mouse hover.
Following is the code.

```
<td> @Html.ActionLink(@item.Split('.')[0], "Usecase", new { name = item }, new {Class = "action add", title = "MyToolTip" })</td>
```

Now I want to add CSS to my Tooltip.How is CSS added to my tool tip?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS by calling on the class `action` or `add`. Both of those are declared as classes for this tooltip in the code you supplied.

For example.

```
.action {
   /*Your styles in here*/
}
```

Comment: This will style the link, I guess @Maha wants to style his tooltip which is displayed when you hover on this link

Comment: @Maha sea this link I think this one is useful for you https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/perfect-tooltip-positioning-with-css-or-js/

Comment: @PriyankPanchal I want exactly what you mean. But it should be styled for a HtmlActionLink in MVC View  rather than treating it as a normal HTML CSS

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement your own tooltip. Please check the example given here https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_tooltip. Create a span containing your tooltip text with visibility hidden. Then on hover of your anchor, set its visibility to visible.

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

<p>Note that the position of the tooltip text isn't very good. Go back to the tutorial and continue reading on how to position the tooltip in a desirable way.</p>
```